# Symfony 3.3.2 Doctrine EntityRepository constructor argument

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm newbie on Symfony. I am trying to update an old project under symfony 2.6 to symfony 3.3.

After multiple bug fixes I am stuck on a point: I have an Error in my EntityRepository.php file with the constructor.

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct(), 1 passed in /Users/.../var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 3434 and exactly 2 expected
```

I understand the error, but my EntityRepository file not contain any __construct method. Should I fix something between Symfony 2 and 3 for the consructor to work?

Thanks a lot.

Here is my MilestoneRepository.php file:

```
namespace MilestonesBundle\Entity\Repository;

use DateTime;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

use Milestones\Entity\Factory\MilestoneFactoryInterface;
use Milestones\Entity\Repository\MilestoneRepositoryInterface;

class MilestoneRepository extends EntityRepository implements MilestoneFactoryInterface, MilestoneRepositoryInterface
{
    protected $current = false;

    /**
     * @see MilestoneFactoryInterface
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $class = $this->getClassName();

        return new $class;
    }

    public function findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        if (!$orderBy) {
            $orderBy['startsAt'] = 'ASC';
        }

        return parent::findBy($criteria, $orderBy, $limit, $offset);
    }

    /**
     * @see MilestoneRepositoryInterface
     */
    public function findCurrent()
    {
        $now = new DateTime;

        if ($this->current === false) {
            $this->current = $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
                ->where('m.startsAt <= :now')
                ->andWhere('(m.endsAt IS NULL OR :now < m.endsAt)')
                ->setParameter('now', $now->format('Y-m-d'))
                ->orderBy('m.startsAt', 'ASC')
                ->setMaxResults(1)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getOneOrNullResult()
            ;
        }

        return $this->current;
    }

    /**
     * @see MilestoneRepositoryInterface
     */
    public function isOpen()
    {
        $current = $this->findCurrent();

        return $current && $current->isStart();
    }
}
```

And here is my EntityRepository.php file:

```
namespace Common\Doctrine\ORM;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository as BaseEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;

class EntityRepository extends BaseEntityRepository
{
    protected $alias = 'x';

    public function add($entity)
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    public function remove($entity)
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    public function findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null, $result = true)
    {
        $alias   = $this->alias;
        $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder($alias);

        $this->applyCriteria($builder, $alias, $criteria);
        $this->applyOrderBy($builder, $alias, $orderBy);
        $this->applyLimit($builder, $limit);
        $this->applyOffset($builder, $offset);

        if (!$result) {
            return $builder;
        }

        return $builder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }

    public function findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $result = true)
    {
        $alias   = $this->alias;
        $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder($alias);

        $this->applyCriteria($builder, $alias, $criteria);
        $this->applyOrderBy($builder, $alias, $orderBy);

        if (!$result) {
            return $builder;
        }

        return $builder->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
    }

    protected function applyCriteria(QueryBuilder $builder, $alias, array $criteria)
    {
        $map = $this->getCriteriaMap();

        foreach ($criteria as $property => $value) {
            if (array_key_exists($property, $map)) {
                call_user_func_array($map[$property], [$builder, $alias, $property, $value]);
            } else {
                $this->applyDefaultCriterion($builder, $alias, $property, $value);
            }
        }
    }

    protected function getCriteriaMap()
    {
        return [];
    }

    protected function applyDefaultCriterion($builder, $alias, $property, $value)
    {
        if (null === $value) {
            $builder->andWhere($alias.'.'.$property.' IS NULL');
        } else {
            $parameter = 'p_' . uniqid();
            $builder->andWhere($alias.'.'.$property.' = :'.$parameter);
            $builder->setParameter($parameter, $value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Apply order by
     *
     * @param  QueryBuilder $builder
     * @param  string       $alias
     * @param  array|null   $orderBy
     * @return void
     */
    protected function applyOrderBy(QueryBuilder $builder, $alias, array $orderBy = null)
    {
        if (empty($orderBy)) {
            $orderBy = $this->getDefaultOrder();
        }

        $map = $this->getOrderingMap();

        foreach ($orderBy as $property => $direction) {
            if (array_key_exists($property, $map)) {
                call_user_func_array($map[$property], [$builder, $alias, $property, $direction]);
            } else {
                $this->applyDefaultOrder($builder, $alias, $property, $direction);
            }
        }
    }

    protected function getDefaultOrder()
    {
        return [];
    }

    protected function getOrderingMap()
    {
        return [];
    }

    protected function applyDefaultOrder(QueryBuilder $builder, $alias, $property, $direction)
    {
        $builder->orderBy($alias.'.'.$property, $direction);
    }

    protected function applyLimit(QueryBuilder $builder, $limit = null)
    {
        if ($limit) {
            $builder->setMaxResults($limit);
        }
    }

    protected function applyOffset(QueryBuilder $builder, $offset = null)
    {
        if ($offset) {
            $builder->setFirstResult($offset);
        }
    }
}
```

I think I'm accessing through a service, with this:

```
services:

# Factories

milestones.factory.milestone:
    alias: milestones.repository.milestone
    arguments: [ MilestonesBundle\Entity\Milestone ]

# Repositories

milestones.repository.milestone:
    class: MilestonesBundle\Entity\Repository\MilestoneRepository
    factory_service: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
    factory_method: getRepository
    arguments: [ MilestonesBundle\Entity\Milestone ]
```

Comment: How are you accessing MilestoneRepository?  Through the entity manager or directly through a service?

Comment: I believe through a service...

Comment: Best to use the edit button and update your question.  Comments don't format well.  It's possible that autowiring is messing you up.  Best to verify exactly how the repository is being accessed.  Given that factory_service, factory method is no longer available in S3.3 then it is clear that your services are not being loaded.

Comment: I think it's good, I use the new factory syntax. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

replace this code:

```
milestones.repository.milestone:
    class: MilestonesBundle\Entity\Repository\MilestoneRepository
    factory_service: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
    factory_method: getRepository
    arguments: [ MilestonesBundle\Entity\Milestone ]
```

with this one:

```
milestones.repository.milestone:
     class: MilestonesBundle\Entity\Repository\MilestoneRepository
     factory: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', getRepository]
     arguments: [ MilestonesBundle\Entity\Milestone ]
```

factory method - [getRepository](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L714)

Answer (score 0):

I think somewhere in jour code this method is called:

```
    public function create()
    {
        $class = $this->getClassName();

        return new $class;
    }
```

And this is calling the constructor of `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`:

```
        public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, Mapping\ClassMetadata $class)
{
    $this->_entityName = $class->name;
    $this->_em         = $em;
    $this->_class      = $class;
}
```

therefore you will have to inject the arguments if you want to use your create method... I think it should be something like `new $class($entityManager, Entity::class)`